# The Proces of arising and passing away

Tags: vipassana

How can you define the experience of *the proces* (or the flow) of raising and passing away of all conditioned things?

Answer (score 1):

as you meditate, one of knowledge reveals to you is consciousness (vinnana) can only take place in one thing at a time, tho it rises and falls in one of the other 4 skanda very quickly.    As you pay attention, when you are aware of a thought (could be anything that is not about 5 sensual pleasures or anger) and dwell in it, (that's a power of nandi) you let go of nundi and consciousness raises back in breathing (form), old thought disappeared.  only this much, one recognizes the raise and fall of name-form.   What other dharma reveals in the process?  you would see the feeling of "self" does not disappear along with disappearing thought.  so you know and see for yourself that a thought isn't you.  this is first clear vision of anatta or non-self.  the ultimate goal is to see of non-self in consciousness.  consciousness is the final burden.

Comment: this is just one aspect of it, since all things raises and falls.  As a matter of fact, perceiving or perception of raising and falling of things (anijja sanna ) is the highest level of karma from Velama Sutta).